# Как найти неправильную работу с памятью?

Tags: c, утечка-памяти, valgrind

Суть проблемы такова: когда в txt файле на вход подается число -8147483645 программа выдает неправильный ответ (когда, например при выборе "+1" выдается число 442450948). Насколько я понял, это какой-то косяк в моей работе с памятью. Удалось выяснить, что где-то в функции num_convert происходит переполнение памяти, отсюда идет неправильный ответ. Но где именно это происходит выяснить не получилось, поэтому прошу помощи в обнаружении проблемы. Привожу, собственно, сам код:

функция num_convert просто каждую цифру числа перемещает в массив

```
void num_convert(long long int num, int ord, long long int* mas, long long int** p)
{

    int counter=ord;
    printf("num %lld\n",num);
    int flag=0;
    int sign=num/abs(num);
    num=abs(num);
    mas=realloc(mas,(ord+1)*sizeof(long long int));
    while (1==1)
    {
        if (num/10==0 && flag==1)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (num/10==0 && flag==0)
        {
            mas[0]=num%10;
            flag++;
        }
        else
        {
            mas[counter]=num%10;
            num=num/10;
            counter--;
        }
    }
    if (sign==-1)
    {
        mas[0]=-1*mas[0];
    }
    *p=mas;
}
```

Далее приведена функция, ответственная за "взаимодействие с пользователем",ее привожу, чтобы было примерно понятно, что вообще происходит в программе и где что может сломаться.

```
int main(void)
{

    long long int** p;
    long long int *m;
    int sw=0;
    int size=0;
    int ord=0;
    long long int n=0;
    int o=0;
    char file_name[255];
    m=(long long int* )malloc(sizeof(long long int));
    p=&m;


    printf("Choose one of the options:\n");
    printf("Enter 1 if you have the number of the elements in your file\n");
    printf("Enter 2 if you do not have the number of the elements in your file\n");
    printf("Enter 3 to shut down the program\n");
    printf(":");
    scanf("%d",&sw);

    switch(sw)
    {
        case(3):
            free(m);
            return 0;
        case(1):
            printf("Enter the name of the file \n");
            scanf("%s", file_name);
            size=read_1(m,file_name,p);
            break;
        case(2):
            printf("Enter the name of the file \n");
            scanf("%s", file_name);
            size=read_2(m,file_name,p);
            break;
    }

    if (size<1)
    {
        printf("An error occured\n");
        free(m);
        return -1;
    }

    n=arr_convert(m,size);
    ord=get_ord(n);
    printf("Choose the scenario (enter +1 or -1) \n");
    scanf("%d",&o);

    switch(o)
    {
        case(1):
            n=n+1;
            ord=get_ord(n);
            num_convert(n,ord,m,p);
            for (int y=0;y<=ord;y++)
            {
                printf("%lld ",m[y]);
            }
            free(m);
            return 0;
        case(-1):
            n=n+1;
            ord=get_ord(n);
            num_convert(n,ord,m,p);
            for (int y=0;y<=ord;y++)
            {
                printf("%lld ",m[y]);
            }
            free(m);
            return 0;
    }
}
```

А таков вывод valgrind

```
==6016== Invalid write of size 8
==6016==    at 0x109467: num_convert (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016==    by 0x108CDC: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016==  Address 0x55ccc90 is 16 bytes after a block of size 48 in arena "client"
==6016== 
==6016== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6016==    at 0x523696A: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==6016==    by 0x523EFA5: printf (printf.c:33)
==6016==    by 0x108D16: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016== 
==6016== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==6016==    at 0x52328FB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==6016==    by 0x5235F9D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==6016==    by 0x523EFA5: printf (printf.c:33)
==6016==    by 0x108D16: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016== 
==6016== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6016==    at 0x5232905: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==6016==    by 0x5235F9D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==6016==    by 0x523EFA5: printf (printf.c:33)
==6016==    by 0x108D16: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016== 
==6016== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6016==    at 0x52360A4: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==6016==    by 0x523EFA5: printf (printf.c:33)
==6016==    by 0x108D16: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016== 
==6016== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6016==    at 0x5236BDC: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==6016==    by 0x523EFA5: printf (printf.c:33)
==6016==    by 0x108D16: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016== 
==6016== Invalid read of size 8
==6016==    at 0x108D00: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016==  Address 0x55ccc78 is 4 bytes after a block of size 36 alloc'd
==6016==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6016==    by 0x1093AA: num_convert (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
==6016==    by 0x108CDC: main (in /home/georgy/Рабочий стол/5 домашка/progr)
```

Примечательно, что как таковых утечек памяти не происходит (со слов самого же valgrind)

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Для десятичного представления числа в переменной типа long long достаточно 19 цифр. (для unsigned long long 20 цифр). И зачем для каждой цифры использовать long long тоже не понятно (достаточно char)/ Поэтому можно ограничиться массивом из 20 байт и ничего динамически не выделять. Вот это -- `int sign=num/abs(num);` и это
    `num=abs(num);` **не будет работать для величины LONG_MIN**. Поэтому вычисления  (получение цифры числа) надо делать с типом `unsigned long long`. Т.е. `unsigned long long v = num < 0 ? -num : num;`

Comment: Имеет смысл не вычислять заренее количество цифр в числе (ваша переменная ord, кстати, возможно ошибка где-то в get_ord()), а получить количество цифр прямо  в ходе получения цифр в `num_convert()` и вернуть эту переменную. Конечно, вы получите цифры в массиве в обратном порядке, после вычислений его надо будет реверсировать.

Comment: @avp , согласен, что long long для каждой цифры -это неправильно (хватил лишнего в процессе переделки под long long),но вот без динамических массивов обойтись не получится (просто потому что задание на эту тему). Код работает на значениях, которые попадают в границы значений int, но за пределами этих границ происходит что-то непонятное , как раз хотелось бы узнать, где тот кусок кода, в котором происходит неправильная работа с памятью. И только после выяснения, где ошибка можно попробовать переделать прогу, ведь в противном случае не исключено, что ошибка повторится.

Comment: У вас, что, задание использовать именно realloc? Все остальное, что я написал о преобразовании числа в массив цифр это не отменяет. Перепишите (и лучше использовать вот такой прототип `long long *num_convert (long long num, long long *mas, size_t *res_length)`, возвращающий указатель на realloc-нутый `mas[]`)

Comment: Конечно, по инерции написал с `long long *`. Надо под каждую цифру использовать char. Тогда прототип будет `char *num_convert (long long num, char *mas, size_t *res_length)`. / И еще, при реализации логично сразу проверить num на 0, а реальные преобразования к массиву цифр провести в другой ветке кода. И не забудьте, что realloc надо будет сделать в конце, а потом скопировать в эту память результат, реверсируя его